# Python: How to print text inputed by user?

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Filename:2_7.py
text=raw_input("Enter string:")
for ?? in range(??)
    print
```

For example, if the user enters `test text`, I want `test text` to be printed on the screen by this code.

What should I write instead of `??` to achieve this purpose?

Comment: What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: -1: Please provide an example of the input and output you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
var = raw_input("Enter something: ")
print "you entered ", var
```

Or in Python 3.x

```
var = input("Enter something: ")
print ("you entered ", var)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to split the string into separate words and print each one?

e.g.

```
for word in text.split():
    print word
```

in action:

```
Enter string: here are some words
here
are
some
words
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a simplistic case, you could try:

```
for word in text.split(" "):
    print word
```

For a more complex case where you want to use a regular expression for a splitter:

```
for word in re.split("\W+", text):
    if word != "":
        print word
```

The earlier example will output `"Hello, my name is Pax."` as:

```
Hello,
my
name
is
Pax.
```

while the latter will more correctly give you:

```
Hello
my
name
is
Pax
```

(and you can improve the regex if you have more edge cases).

Comment: why do you need the square brackets? what's the difference between splitting on \W+ and [\W]+ ?. Why is it you have to check for "" ??

Comment: I left the square brackets in from an earlier invocation since I was checking for multiple characters. You're right that they're not needed in this case. The reason I check for an empty string is specifically because of the ending period. By splitting that sample sentence on `\W+`, you get an empty element at the end, or beginning if you're working in one of those languages that has punctuation at the start. ¿yes?